# Lighttpd error log increases too fast

Tags: logging, lighttpd

I am using **lighttpd v1.4.35** and I have developed a simple web page with some links to test.

After some clicks I have noticed the error log **is increasing too fast**. In /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf I have the server.errorlog path set as:

```
server.errorlog             = "/myPartition/myFolder/error.log"
```

An example of an entry in the error log:

```
2015-02-19 13:41:28: (log.c.164) server started 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.339) -- splitting Request-URI 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.340) Request-URI     :  /versions.php 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.341) URI-scheme      :  http 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.342) URI-authority   :  172.22.196.7 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.343) URI-path (raw)  :  /versions.php 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.344) URI-path (clean):  /versions.php 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.345) URI-query       :   
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (mod_access.c.135) -- mod_access_uri_handler called 
2015-02-19 13:41:57: (response.c.473) -- before doc_root
```

What parameter should I configure in order to register just errors, not anything I click or select?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your config, you have this line:

```
debug.log-request-handling = "enable"
```

Comment it out by putting a `#` in front of it.

To find out where it is, you can use grep:

```
grep -nr 'log-request-handling' /etc/lighttpd/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some debug options enabled in your configuration. Check your configuration against information on [lighttpd debug documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/DebugVariables) page and disable any extra debug logging.